# Should I keep Alien Containment?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

1. Is there a point in keeping Alient Containment after all interrogations are complete?
2. Is there a point in capturing live aliens that were already interrogated besides intact weapon?

Comment: Are you sure you've captured all the aliens?  Some of them don't show up till relatively late game.

Comment: Intact weapons are useful. Means you don't have to spend as much precious elerium outfitting your squad. Also, especially if you're training up a new rookie, the upgraded arc thrower is a lot more accurate at point blank than a squaddie who still needs to learn to aim a plasma rifle.

Comment: But OOTH, a 38th Plasma Rifle is less useful than a couple of Weapon Fragments...

Comment: As far as I know, you can still use Arc Throwers on aliens even if you don't have containment. You'll stun the alien, get the item, but not actually capture a live alien.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no point keeping Alien Containment after you have finished all your alien research or just captured and interrogated an Etheral (which gives you all credit anyway).

In fact - there is a bonus because when you remove the alien containment any extra 'live' aliens will die, and you get their corpses to sell or use.

The only small bug - the engineer and scientist will keep 'verbally' asking you to build an alien containment (like at the beginning of the game).

Note: you do NOT need alien containment to capture aliens for their weapons only.

Comment: Will stunned aliens expire and be added to your corpse stock if you don't have AC?

Comment: @kotekzot yes, they will be added as soon as you return to base

Comment: Note that you usually won't have any extra 'live' aliens, since the interrogation kills them *(you get another corpse, and the autopsy option if you haven't already dissected that alien)*.  You'll only have live aliens if you captured extras.

Comment: So then there's no reason to capture aliens you've already interrogated other than to get an intact weapon? Is there any other way to get an intact weapon? (will that happen randomly, sometimes?)

Comment: Correct - no reason to get them again other than for weapons. No other way to get intact weapons (other than building them)

Comment: "Is there any other way to get an intact weapon" - Yes. Mind Control on an alien disables the self-destruct on its weapon (while it's under your control): so when its teammates kill it, its weapon is left intact and recovered by your squad without any Arc Thrower.