# Will I get corpses if enemies were stunned?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

I'm playing XCOM: Enemy Within.

I've already researched all the corpses type and had lots of plasma weapons for my entire troops.  It seems no need to stun enemies and capture them alive.

Will I get corpses if I stun the enemies instead of kill them?

If I can only get their weapons and nothing else, maybe I don't need to bother capture them any more.

Thanks for the answers :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you won't get corpses, assuming you have the Alien Containment Facility (based on you mentioning that you've researched them) you won't get a corpse, you could think of the aliens as being held 'in prison' by you.

Once you've researched all captured aliens there isn't any need for an Arc Thrower.  If you are only part way through the game you could have 1 soldier carry one, but the slot is best used for something useful.

Comment: capturing is still useful even if you're done with research just to get additional plasma weapons without having to build them.

Comment: Only to a very minor point.  If you've not researched plasma weapons, sure, it can be useful to have a free gun, but the risk of getting close enough to stun them for 1 gun against the XP for a kill isn't really worth it - especially if you have actually researched them and can just buy them from the Workshop.  I guess it will depend on each individual playstyle.

Comment: Thanks for the answers and suggestions.  

Actually I've already got bunch of plasma weapons way far enough for all my entire troops even rookies got one. lol  

If all additional captives are imprisoned, I do thinks it'll be crazy crowded since I often stun lots of aliens D:

Seems Arc Thrower only use to repair Mec and S.H.I.V now I think :D

Answer (score 3):

Stunned enemies are stored in the containment facility, so you don't immediately get their corpses.  However, once you destroy the containment facility, you [do get their corpses](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/92141/2578).

If you don't have a containment facility, you will get corpses immediately.